# Wrong rendering when I'm using EffectComposer in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have two scenes: one with the plane and another with the box. I want to blur the box.
Rendering loop:

```
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  renderer.clearDepth();

  composer.render();
```

In this case only blurred box appeared, but plane is missing.
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bq5m1u6v/36/